# Can a Chrome Extension detect if the Google Play Store is enabled or disabled on a Chromebook?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension, chromebook

Chromebooks have an option, "Remove Google Play Store" in their settings. Is it possible for a Chrome browser extension (by itself) to detect if the Play Store is enabled or disabled on the Chromebook? If that is so, then how?

I don't see anything obvious in the Extension API docs to do this, but sometimes functionality can be somewhat obscure. Maybe there's a way to use the available APIs that I don't know about?
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index

Or maybe there's some other way...?

Thanks for any recommendations you can give!!

Comment: Try [chrome.management](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management).

Comment: @wOxxOm as far as I can tell there is nothing there that will assist. For example, `chrome.management.getAll()` lists installed extensions and apps (Drive, Slides, LastPass, Hangouts, Calculator, etc)... but it doesn't list the Play Store (nor Android Studio, nor gedit, all of which are installed on my Chromebook).

Comment: Then there's no such API and I guess you'll have to write a separate utility that will run in ChromeOS natively and communicate over an HTTP port to your extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do it, but it isn't particularly secure. If someone else has a better way, please post it. Here is what I've found.

The Chromebook user must open this URL up in their Chrome browser and enable extensions on `chrome://` URLS:

```
chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls
```

The Chrome extension must have the following in its manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [
{
    "js": ["my-content-script-file.js"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "matches": [
        "chrome://os-settings/androidappsdetails",
        "chrome://os-settings/apps",
        "chrome://os-settings/"
    ]
}]
```

If everything is set up as I said above, then, when the settings window is open, the `my-content-script-file.js` file of the Chrome extension can read the HTML and add on-click events to the DOM elements in the settings window, just like a normal content script could with any other webpage.